# python swap sort not giving correct output

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to sort an array where it starts from the second number and looks at the one before it to see if the previous number is larger. If it is, I want to swap the numbers, otherwise keep the number where it is. Currently my code does not do that. When I input the array below the only thing that changes is that the 2 becomes an 11, giving me two 11's in the middle. What is going wrong?

```
#given an array of digits a of length N
a = [7, 3, 11, 2, 6, 16]
N = len(a)

# moving forward along a starting from the second position to the end

# define _sillysort(a, start_pos):
#     set position = start_pos
#     moving backwards along a from start_pos:
#         if the a[position-1] is greater than a[position]:
#             swap a[position-1] and a[position]
def sillysort(a, start_pos):
    a_sorted = []
    start_pos = a[1]
    for position in a:
        if a[start_pos-1] >= a[start_pos]:
            a[start_pos-1], a[start_pos] = a[start_pos], a[start_pos-1]
        else:
            a[start_pos-1] = a[start_pos]
        a_sorted.append(position)
        position += 1
    return a_sorted
```

When I run this, sillysort(a, N), I get this output [7, 3, 11, 11, 6, 16].

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of issues

`start_pos = a[1]`

If you are already providing start_pos as an argument to your function, why are you reinitialising it in the function. Moreover, if `a` is the array you want to sort, why is the `start_pos` of your algorithm the second element of the array `a` itself?

```
for position in a:
        if a[start_pos-1] >= a[start_pos]:
            a[start_pos-1], a[start_pos] = a[start_pos], a[start_pos-1]
        else:
            a[start_pos-1] = a[start_pos]
        a_sorted.append(position)
        position += 1
```

The `for in` loop will iterate through the array `a` and `position` will take the values of the elements of the array. In your example `position` will take the values in the following order:

`7, 3, 11, 2, 6, 16`

What I don't understand is why are you incrementing position by 1 at the end of the the for loop. And once again, you are using the values inside the array to index the array rather than the indices themselves.

Since in your example, `start_pos` will take the value `a[1]` i.e. 3, your code compares a[3] and a[2] i.e. 2 and 11 and goes into the else condition and makes a[3] = a[2] and hence you get 11 in the position of 2

You have probably confused yourself with the variable names. See if this helps you.